# How to add a click handler on a button in Chrome and still have the default action

Tags: jquery, post, forms, http-post

The following works in Firefox:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', ->
  $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  $(this).val('Sending')
)
```

The idea is to prevent double-clicking (there are other issues with the above, but not the subject of this question). However, in Chrome what happens is the form never gets submitted. The click event prevents the default action (submitting the form) from happening!

I could do something like `form.submit()` at the end, but then in Firefox it would submit twice? I guess I'd have to do `e.preventDefault()`... Is there an easy solution here? Should I instead be listening for a form submit event?

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way would be is to

--> attach the event to the button

--> Prevent the default action

--> Submit the form

This should work on both the browsers. You are on the right path.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  $(this).val('Sending')
  form.submit()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').one('click', function() { setTimeout(function(){ return false; }, 20); });
```

Answer (score 0):

i know 2 ways ([look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzUc9/)) to set event handdler and still have default action

1.- with javascript:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1"); 

btn.addEventListener && btn.addEventListener("click", FunctionName, false) ||
btn.attachEvent && btn.attachEvent("onclick", FunctionName);
```

2.-with jquery:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event){
    //do something
    if(!Valid)
    {
        //prevent default action()
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```